# Install WiX Bootstrapper Prerequisite Before Displaying UI

Tags: wix, burn, wix3.9

Is it possible to have one or more prerequisites installed before the Burn custom user interface? The scenario I have in mind is that the custom user interface depends on the prerequisites.

The documentation I have found thus far indicates that you use the Chain element to install multiple packages. The packages are installed in the order that they are listed in the Chain element. However none of the documentation I have found indicates at which point when the UI is actually displayed or how to control this?

One document on [How To: Install the .NET Framework Using Burn](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/redistributables_and_install_checks/install_dotnet.html) seems to suggest that this may not be possible. For example it contains the following sentences.

"Target your bootstrapper application to the version of .NET built into the operating system. For Windows 7, this is .NET 3.5."

Why would it specifically state that you need to target the version of .NET built into the operating system if you could be certain that the version of .NET you included in the bootstrapper would be available at the time the UI is displayed?

Comment: Just curious if you ever discovered the answer to this question. I'm facing the same problem currently.

Answer (score 0):

When you run the installer generated by your Wix Bundle the Managed Bootstrapper starts at the point:

```
protected override Run()
```

After this you can do the various installation phases such as Detect, Plan and Apply. Showing your UI is simply using the .Show() method on a wpf page for example. Therefore you could delay showing the user your Ui till whenever you want in the installation.

As for targeting it at a .Net version, if you run your installer without the targeted .Net installed it will attempt to install it which is done by another .Net installer. I assume they are suggesting you target the version installed on that operating system so that you avoid having the end user install two things in a row.